# Converting nx1 column matrix to √n x √ n square matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to convert nx1 column matrix to √n x √ n square matrix
e.g;

Given the 9x1 matrix:

```
A = 10
     9
     8
     7
     6
     5
     4
     3
     2
```

I want to convert it into 3x3 matrix as:

```
10    9    8
 7    6    5
 4    3    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using [**`reshape`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function as follows:

```
B = reshape(A, [3 3]).'
```

Comment: @Sam You'll actually want `reshape(A, [3 3]).'` (note the dot) because `'` is [not a transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html#buuhgyz).

Comment: @Suever I tried `reshape(A,[3,3])'` and it served the purpose. I also checked `reshape(A, [3 3]).'` which gives the same result. I am using MATLAB2015a

Comment: @Sam For real numbers they *will* give the same result but it's good to get in the habit of using the dot because if you ever have a complex number it will fail since `'` is actually the complex conjugate (which just so happens to look like the transpose for real numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
a = (1:9).';
n = size(a,1)^0.5;
A(n,n) = 0;
A(:) = a(:);
```

Which will be faster if you already have `n`, the size of the resulted matrix, defined, so you can write `A(3,3) = 0`, without defining `n`.